# Need to understand the steps in this proof

Tags: real-analysis

regarding the following function:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm3Lv.png]

**Now please look at these steps:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfC42.png]

In Line $(1)$ of picture $2$, why is $|x|$ inside the integral and not in the integral upper limit?

And in Line $(2)$, where did the inequality come from. We have not taken the supremum yet? And what is that vertical bar in the upper limit of the integral and next to x?

Answer (score 1):

In the first line indeed the integral should be: $$\int_{0}^{2|x|} |f(y)|dy$$

Now since the function you are integrating over is non-negative, and $[0,|x|]\subset[0,2|x|]$,  you get that $$\int_{0}^{2|x|}|f(y)|dy\geq\int_{0}^{|x|} |f(y)|dy$$

Another way to think of it is as writing: $$\int_{0}^{2|x|} |f(y)|dy =\int_{0}^{|x|} |f(y)|dy+\int_{|x|}^{2|x|} |f(y)|dy\geq\int_{0}^{|x|} |f(y)|dy,$$ since $\int_{|x|}^{2|x|} |f(y)|dy\geq0$

As for the vertical bar, its a typo, the upper limit of integration should be $|x|$ and the function that's being integrated should be |f(y)|